# alert after click chip in materialize in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I have the following chip with materialize:

```
<div class="chip">
  tag
  <i class="close material-icons" ng-click="hide_chip(this)">close</i>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
$scope.hide_chip = function(elem){
        var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (r == true) {
            var chip = elem.parentNode;
            chip.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

I want to know how to show an alert when user clicks the close icon?
the alert should have yes or no button if it is yes the chip close, but if user click no the chip does not close

My error is "chip is undefined", and when r is false the chip disappears

Someone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event

```
<div class="chip">
    Tag
    <i class="close material-icons" ng-click="hide_chip($event)">close</i>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.hide_chip = function($event){
  var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (r == true) {
    var chip = $event.target.parentNode;
    chip.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Check a demo here
http://jsfiddle.net/f7utj5dr/

Comment: my friend thanks, I have edited my question can you help me?

Comment: You can use a confirm box and if yes is clicked then hide the chip
@DiegoIsraelMoreno Edited my answer. pls check

Comment: I got this chip is undefined :( I do the same with angularjs and ng-click

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno It's working for the code that you've posted here. Check the fiddle. If your code is different from the code that you've put in the question, then can you post the whole segment of code?